# Huge replication lag after upgrading from Mysql 5.7 to Mysql 8.0.32

Tags: mysql, lag, database-replication

In my setup I have one source and one single replica. The replication has always been working fine on MySQL 5.7. Recently we have upgraded to **MySQL 8.0.32** and since that we are constantly experiencing high lag in replica compared to source. The replication is based on binary logs (not migrated to GTID).

**Things I've tried so far:**

- restarting mysql service at replica
- checking network/CPU utilization
- checking allocated memory and memory utilization
- checking disk reads and writes
- looking for long running user queries at replica and killing them so they wouldnt block the replication SQL thread.
- checking for replicated tables without primary keys: we have 5 of these tables, but none of them is larger than 100k records.

I would appreciate any sort of hint on what else to check to find the root cause for the lag and also how to fix it.

SHOW REPLICA STATUS :

Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
Seconds_Behind_Master: 76824
Last_IO_Errno: 0
Last_IO_Error:
Last_SQL_Errno: 0
Last_SQL_Error:
SQL_Delay: 0
SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
Slave_SQL_Running_State: Waiting for dependent transaction to commit
Master_Retry_Count: 86400
Master_Bind:
Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:

SHOW PROCESSLIST

8      event_scheduler      localhost           Daemon  244034  Waiting on empty queue
44636   system user         connecting host     Connect 19361   Waiting for source to send event
44637   system user         Query                        0      Waiting for dependent transaction to commit
44638   system user         Query   78677   Applying batch of row changes (update)

**Edit:**

mysql is hosted on Azure VM
OS version   Windows Server 2019 Datcenter
RAM size 256 GB
number of cores  32
any SSD   Premium SSD LRS

Please find additional information at: https://justpaste.it/aizb0

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Additional DB information request from your REPLICA server, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions to reduce LAG.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck thanks for your input! I have updated the post with these info, plus i pasted a justpaste link. Please let me know if you need any more details to be able to help, looking forward for your reply! Thanks, Peter

Comment: Peter, Thanks for posting your data.  Analysis in process with available data.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your Azure portal, SETTINGS, Server parameters

```
innodb_thread_concurrency=0  # from 65 to avoid overloading CPU's let system manage
max_connections=512  # from 10000 - max_used_connections was 149 for the day
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm=.00001  # from 10% to enable pre-flushing earlier
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=.00001  # from 90% to reduce pages_dirty of 157,602
read_rnd_buffer_size=16384  # from 262144 to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 160,262
```

These are only 5 to relieve pressure points causing lag as a reaction - there are MANY more.

Observations from SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
com_rollback had 6,355 incidents AVG 1 every 17 seconds takes many resources, prevent if you can - usually there are methods to avoid.

com_savepoint had 35 counted, normally we see com_release_savepoint with a matching value.
Your com_release_savepoint was 0, indicating resources not released.

select_scan frequency 88 RPS can be avoided with indexes - RPhr 315,423

View profile, please.

Comment: @Peter-Hamori  Any progress on reducing your REPLICA Lag?